# How to get JWT token from "Response Header" in angular 6

Tags: angular, jwt

I am developing an angular 6 application. After entering login credential backend validates the user credentials and sent me a JWT token with headers. Like below-mentioned details. How can I get JWT token in the angular application before redirect to dashboard from login page?

### Response Header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Cache-Control: private

Content-Length: 138

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2019 11:29:02 GMT
```

**jwt: eyJhbGciOiJIUz...**

Location: http://localhost:4200

I tried using with HttpHeader but getting null value only.

```
let header = new HttpHeaders();
console.log('read header jwt token', header.get('jwt'));
const token = header.get('jwt');
localStorage.setItem('token', token);
```

Comment: hm, provide more informations or create minimal demo so we can check.

Comment: Usually tokens are sent as the body of the response. Are you sure it's in the headers in your case?

Comment: Also the code in the question doesn't make sense. You're creating a new `HttpHeaders` object and want to get `jwt` from there, which surely won't be there

Comment: @igor_c. Yes I am getting a response from header

Answer (score -1):

I have same issue during my API call, below code work for me.

```
http.get<any>('http://localhost:4200')
      .subscribe(resp => {
       console.log('token', header.get('jwt'));
       const token = header.get('jwt');
       localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      });
```

Comment: http.get<any> is this HttpClient or HttpHeaders?

Comment: @imjayabal http requests are always done with `HttpClient`

Comment: how would that work, you didn't define `header` anywhere.

Comment: @imjayabal I didn't send any code. If you're really getting the token in the headers, try something like this: `this.http.get(url, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(resp => console.log(resp.headers))`